# How to get rid of dummy interface?

Tags: linux, networking

Hey guys I have a strange problem. There isn't an eth0 interface on my Linux embedded (ttylinux v7) client instead I have a dummy0 interface.

With this interface I can't ping anything, and I think it does not work at all.

If I run udhcpc to retrieve an IP during the boot process I can't get one (Sending discover.. No lease, failing). If I do the same after the login it works but the dummy0 continues there. That is strange because its a PXE boot so my dhcp server is running since the boot begins.

I've already put the `NOZEROCONF` option on `/etc/network.conf`.

Comment: `rmmod dummy` will probably get rid of it. But it's not the cause of you not having a working Ethernet interface.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The command `ip link delete dummy0` is what you would use to delete it at the command line.  I have no idea why a dummy interface is getting created on your system though.

Answer (score 2):

`rmmod dummy` will remove the dummy module used to create the dummy interface.
You will always get `dummy0` interface when the module is loaded.

Comment: Can't remove it under Debian 10 because... `rmmod: ERROR: Module dummy is builtin.`